# Tensorflow: get predicted values from test samples

Tags: tensorflow, perceptron

I am trying to get the predicted values after training MLP and I do the following

```
sess.run(tf.argmax(labels_test, 1), feed_dict={X: data_test, dropout_keep_prob: 1.})
```

Unfortunately, above line generate same result as this line

```
sess.run(tf.argmax(labels_test, 1))
```

So something is wrong with my code. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`labels_test` is suspicious: it looks like the labels of your test data, **not** the labels *predicted* by your model.  If this is the case, then it's not a function of `data_test` and there's no reason it should be any different a result.  In short, the likely problem is that you are not actually calling `sess.run()` on your model, but just on some fixed labels of the test data.

That said, I am speculating since there is not enough detail to actually inspect and solve the problem.  If a more thorough answer is desired, please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. One way to do this

```
accuracy1, prediction1 = sess.run([accuracy, pred], feed_dict={X: data_test, y: labels_test, dropout_keep_prob: 1.})
```

Or just to get the predicted values

```
predicted_values = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={X: data_test, y: labels_test, dropout_keep_prob: 1.})
```